# Django unable to find my custom template tags?

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I'm creating custom template tags for my django site. I've followed the django documentation for this and have created a `templatetags` directory in my main application.

```
/project/apps/core/templatetags
                 -/__init__.py
                 -/core_extras.py
```

Since I am not sure if this is causing the problem, I should note I have this in my `settings.py`

```
sys.path.insert(0, join(PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django_evolution',
'apps.core',
)
```

### core_extras.py

```
from django import template
import settings

register = template.Library()

class SiteNameNode(template.Node):
def __init__(self):

def render(self, context):
    site_name = getarrr(settings, "SITE_NAME", false)
    if not site_name:
        return "<!-- SITE_NAME not setting in Settings -->"
    if settings.DEBUG:
        return 'Debug || ' + site_name
    return site_name
@register.tag(name="site_name")
def find_site_name(parser, token):
return SiteNameNode()
```

### main.html

```
{% load core_extras %}
```

### Error

```
In template /cygdrive/d/Users/Kin/BitNami DjangoStack projects/flipfinder/templates/main.html, error at line 1
'core_extras' is not a valid tag library: Template library core_extras not found, tried django.templatetags.core_extras,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.core_extras
```

**Has anyone else run into a problem like this? Am I missing something obvious. I've went through and double checked everything, but I can't seem to find anyone with a similar problem.**

Comment: just to make sure did you put an __init__.py in both your core and apps folder ?

Comment: Yes, all of my apps are confirmed working before I tried to load the custom tag.

Comment: Tip: Go into the shell and try to `from apps.core.templatetags import core_extras` - if there's an error in the file, that'll tell you the real one.  Like sdolan said in his answer, django's template system is horrid at reporting the _real_ errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's failing to import because of a syntax error.  Django's templating system just swallows it up.

This line:

```
site_name = getarrr(settings, "SITE_NAME", false)
```

should be:

```
site_name = getattr(settings, "SITE_NAME", false)
```