# Custom tag not loaded in template

Tags: django, django-templates, pygments

I've created a custom tag that I want to use, but Django can't seem to find it.  My `templatetags` directory is set up like this:

[image]

**pygmentize.py**

```
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_by_name
from django import template
from pygments.formatters.other import NullFormatter

register = template.Library()

@register.tag(name='code')
def do_code(parser,token):
    code = token.split_contents()[-1]
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endcode',))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return CodeNode(code,nodelist)

class CodeNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self,lang,code):
        self.lang = lang
        self.nodelist = code

    def render(self,context):
        code = self.nodelist.render(context)
        lexer = get_lexer_by_name('python')
        return highlight(code,lexer,NullFormatter())
```

I am trying to use this tag to render code in `gameprofile.html`.

**gameprofile.html**

```
(% load pygmentize %}
{% block content %}
    <title>{% block title %} | {{ game.title }}{% endblock %}</title>
    <div id="gamecodecontainer">
        {% code %}
            {{game.code}}
        {% endcode %}
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

When I navigate to `gameprofile.html`, I get an error:

> Invalid block tag on line 23: 'code', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: does `{% do_code %}{% endcode %}` work? (is it ignoring the name)

Comment: I've tried, and `do_code` doesn't work either.

Comment: Hmm, the only thing that really looks out of place then to me is the fact that you have a block inside of  a block... not sure if that would affect things or not (the title). (I could be wrong, I don't think I use any nested blocks)

Comment: The title has been there for a while and hans't been a problem. Although there is also a block inside a block for the `{% code %}` section too...

Comment: Yeah I was referring more to explicitly the `block` tag, again but I guess there could be times when you only want a block to show if another is present... I can't really see any thing wrong with your code here, of course I presume that you've restarted the `runserver` command

Comment: Yup, at least a few times. No luck.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really see the problem here... the only difference between your code and any of the django source code is that they ignore the `name=` (`.tag('code')` for example), as a simple test you could try just adding a different `simple_tag` or similar and see if that is able to be rendered, it would at least reduce the bug scope from module to node

Comment: I've tried changing up the `simple_tag`, but still the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: I've just read that there is the chance that you're getting a syntax error that is stopping the import without telling you ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8177742/1324033))... You could try changing the code to the [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#parsing-until-another-block-tag-and-saving-contents) tag code to verify this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101850/discussion-between-sayse-and-tk-421).

Comment: Generally the message "Did you forget to register or load this tag?" is linked with a mispell of a django tag.

Answer (score 25):

For Django 2.2 up to 3, you have to load **staticfiles** in html template first before use **static** keyword

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
```

For other versions use **static**

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
```

Also you have to check that you defined **STATIC_URL** in *setting.py*

At last, make sure the static files exist in the defined folder

Comment: for Django 3.0 this results in the error: django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library.

So it seems like "load static" is the correct command at least for Django 3.0+

Comment: For Django 3 use only  `{% load static %}`

Answer (score 17):

The error is in this line: `(% load pygmentize %}`, an invalid tag.
Change it to `{% load pygmentize %}`

Comment: Uh, those are the same string. ?

Comment: No one starts with a parentheses and one with a bracket

Comment: FYI... I had a similar issue but had spacing incorrect.  I had { % load static % }, but it needed to be {% load static %}

Answer (score 11):

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image">
```

in your templates, use the static template tag to build the URL for the given relative path using the configured `STATICFILES_STORAGE`.

Answer (score 10):

did you try this

```
{% load games_tags %}
```

at the top instead of pygmentize?

Comment: why? Pygmentize is replaced with game_tags? there is no file with game_tags name

Comment: There is no "game_tags" in the original post. This answer is not helpful.

Answer (score 7):

```
{% load static %}
```

Please add this template tag on top of the HTML or base HTML file

Answer (score 5):

Encountered this same issue but I just added `{% load static %}` from my extends template and it worked. So in your case if you're trying to load `gameprofile.html` from a base template you just need to add it like this:

```
{% extends 'some_base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load pygmentize %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, here's how I solved it.  Following the first section of [this very excellent Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/), I did the following:

1. Create a new Django app by executing: `python manage.py startapp new_app`
2. Edit the `settings.py` file, adding the following to the list of `INSTALLED_APPS`: `'new_app',`
3. Add a new module to the `new_app` package named `new_app_tags`.
4. In a Django HTML template, add the following to the top of the file, but after `{% extends 'base_template_name.html' %}`: `{% load new_app_tags %}`
5. In the `new_app_tags` module file, create a custom template tag (see below).
6. In the same Django HTML template, from step 4 above, use your shiney new custom tag like so: `{% multiply_by_two | "5.0" %}`
7. Celebrate!

Example from step 5 above:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def multiply_by_two(value):
    return float(value) * 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The app that contains the custom tags must be in `INSTALLED_APPS`. So Are you sure that your directory is in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/):

> The app that contains the custom tags must be in `INSTALLED_APPS` in order for the `{% load %}` tag to work. This is a security feature: It allows you to host Python code for many template libraries on a single host machine without enabling access to all of them for every Django installation.

Comment: The `games` app is included in installed apps.

Comment: The app that contains the custom tags which here is templatetags

Comment: I get `ImportError: No module named templatetags`

Comment: I Think you should put it in installed app as games.templatetags

Comment: This is just wrong, there isn't any problem with where the op is storing their template tag and they are not classed as an app

Comment: Yes, I've edited my comment therefore. And if you refer that it should not be at the INSTALLED_APPS, I think it is what stated in docummentation [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: The only app here is `games` and that must be included because otherwise the actual  template the op is trying to render their tag in wouldn't be available.

Comment: Yes I know. Mmm, the only thing I'm thinking of now is a name conflict of the templatetag "code".

Answer (score 0):

In `gameprofile.html` please change the tag `{% endblock content %}` to `{% endblock %}` then it works otherwise django will not load the *endblock* and give error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes all you need is to just:

1. Restart the django server by pressing **Ctrl + C**

or

2. Hard reload the page by pressing **Shift + Ctrl + R**

Answer (score 0):

Remember {% your code %} is different from { % your code % } check the spaces before the bracket the brackets

Answer (score -2):

You need to change:

```
{% endblock content %}
```

to

```
{% endblock %}
```