# How to add social sharing buttons in Django template?

Tags: python, django

I googled and searched similar questions on Stackoverflow, but couldn't make it due to lack of details. I know how to get the current url `{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}` but I don't know how to use this to share the content in different social apps?

Comment: Did you try plugins like this one?
https://pypi.org/project/django-social-widgets/

Comment: I tried, but it lacks detail, I get errors while trying to impliment it

Comment: I added `{% social_widget_render "twitter/share_button.html" href="http://www.twitter.com" username="BillGates"  %}` in template, but getting this error `Invalid block tag on line 29: 'social_widget_render', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35054230/django-did-you-forget-to-register-or-load-this-tag

Comment: I know what is that error and I don't think this link helps

Comment: https://github.com/creafz/django-social-widgets/tree/master/example_project

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out how to use `django-social-widgets` and here are possible Errors you may encounter and their solutions:

1. Python Django custom template tags register.assignment_tag not working

`AttributeError: 'Library' object has no attribute 'assignment_tag'`

Solution:

rename `assignment_tag` to `simple_tag`. Since, former is deprecated and `simple_tag` is used instead.

2. Error: TypeError context must be a dict rather than Context

   ```
   try:
       t = loader.get_template(template)
       return t.render(Context(kwargs))
   except TemplateDoesNotExist:
       return ''
   ```

replace above code with:

```
try:
    t = loader.get_template(template)
    return t.render(kwargs)   # here
```